# Which platform has good job openings in Oracle 91 & 10g

Tags: oracle

I plan to do an Oracle course in Dream infotech. They are providing training in Oracle on Linux / Solaris. Which platform is best and has good job openings?

Answer (score 1):

Solaris is probably your better bet.  People willing to spend the bucks on Sun Support are more likely to choose a commercial database to run on it.

Comment: You can run Solaris without Sun Support (We do in a lot of cases). And RHEL costs more than Solaris support last time I checked.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should have plenty of job offerings. Solaris is probably still slightly more common in enterprise, but Linux seems to be growing far faster than it. Either way, I don't think you'll be disadvantaged whichever one you choose. My advice would be to install them, and play around a bit, and then specialize in the one you like the most.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I think either is fine on the short term. On the long term, I think we'll see more Linux and less Solaris. Most new Oracle installations around here are Linux or Windows these days.

As for Oracle training, it probably won't matter much what platform your training is on, as long as it's on a *NIX. I would have no problem hiring someone trained on Oracle/Solaris even if Linux was my primary platform or vice versa.